# boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address

Tags: c++, сокет, boost

Доброго времени суток!

Использую boost::asio::ip::udp::socket для чтения данных с определенного адреса и порта. Насколько я понял, boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address дает возможность заново использовать адрес другим сокетом, после того, как первый сокет закрыт.  Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы два сокета ОДНОВРЕМЕННО считывали данные с одного и того адреса и порта?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А зачем? Вы хотите считывать одно и то же два раза, или читать в два раза быстрее?

Comment: Читать одно и то же два раза для двух устройств, т.е. у нас есть два объекта, у каждого из которых свой сокет и каждый должен считывать с одного порта